# OpenSSL certificate: self-signed cert for composer install

Tags: ssl, terminal, openssl, composer-php, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to run composer install while inside a secure network with ipv4 enabled. The current issue is the Self-signed certs cause a security error when running the commands inside the network. When I run it outside the network (without ipv4), it works perfectly.

I have tried a few different methods, like making a certificate file and including it in composer.json under the options field. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

SSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed

Thank you.